# How do I change my account password on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

I searched for the option "change password" in my account, but I didn't find it. Is it possible? If it is possible, how do I do it?

Comment: Go to your profile -> Edit Profile & Settings -> My Logins -> Change password.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your network profile from AskUbuntu profile.

[image]

2. On your network profile click `my logins` (blue link next to the "About Me" section )

[image]

You will be presented with popup window with an option to change profile

Answer (score 0):

To change [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com) account password, Click on your User Icon on the top --> Go to **Edit Profile & Settings** --> **My Logins** --> **Change password**